# iPhone Wireless Ad Hoc App Distribution

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I would like to distribute my ipa file from website link.  But trying to follow the instructions is impossible, because the only options for distributing the app are:

Debug
Release
AdHoc

Over Air Distribution is not in the list.  Do we need to upgrade our license, or is there some other configuration setting that I need to do to get this option available?

Comment: Have you tried [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/)? It's free and it works great. (I am not affiliated with them.)

Comment: What do you mean by Ad Hoc Distribution? Is it that you want people to test your application before it goes to App Store? If so, TestFlight is indeed a great solution (though, one can do it by hand). Would you like to distribute your production app among your clients only? Then you need iOS Developer Enterprise Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Updated) Easiest Way:**

I have found another way to distribute the ipa.

http://www.diawi.com/

This website provide service to distribute you adhoc app (ipa).

**Another way:**

To Distribute your app to other device your have to register those device in your developer account.

To AdHoc distribution you need the devices UDID.... register those in developer account and make a AdHoc profile and sign your app using the profile.
After that send the AdHoc profile and your app to the Users...

Comment: Yes, I've done all of this and sent via email the .ipa file.  However, I've been looking at instructions for putting the .ipa file and a .plist file on a web server, such that those with registered devices can click on the web page's link and the app will install.

Comment: You can't install the app you only have one choice to provide the AdHoc certificate & the .ipa file. User have to drag those two file on the iTunes remaining iphone connected. then the app will be available to install in apps tab in iTunes.

Comment: The instructions all say that I should have an option to choose "Over Air Distribution" but that option is not available.  The only options I get in my list are "Debug", "Release", and "AdHoc".  Then, when it's time to choose the "Validate" or "Distribute" button, the instructions also show a "Share" button that I don't have.

Comment: I've looked at several answers and tutorials for doing this and they all say or show the same thing.  Here is the link to a good one with pictures and step-by-step instructions:

http://www.cannonballbounce.com/content/iphone-wireless-ad-hoc-app-distribution

Comment: You have another option to implement TestFlight. Upload your app in TestFlight by signing the Adhoc profile and send email to users from TestFlight. If user click the link provided in email then the app will be automatically install in their iPhone...

Comment: From the link the you provided: There will be no option to select 'Over Air Distribution', you have to rename a scheme. Please read the Step 2

Comment: Hi, Aminul:  This is a procedure that installs the AdHoc distribution "without" using iTunes.  It appears that people are doing this.  It appears the process has changed, so I'm looking for folks who know how to do it.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Aminul:  One more thing:  I followed the instruction creating a duplicate of the Release giving it a "Over Air Distribution" name, but when I get to the Distribution part I still do not see the Share button, so do I hit the Distribute button and select ""Export as Export Archive"?

Comment: I tried that but didn't get the .ipa file, so I'm still lost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32088/discussion-between-aminul-and-patricia-larue)

Comment: i encourage you to implement TestFlight, if you want to automatically install the app on users iphone.
Because I far i know there is no procedure to install your app using Adhoc profile without user's interaction.User have to drag those two file on the iTunes remaining iphone connected. then the app will be available to install in apps tab in iTunes.